# Power Query Nested Joined Queries and First Occurrence

Tags: sql, excel

I'm still learning quite a bit about power query editor and SQL so bare with me on this.

My Problem:
I am trying to find the first occurrence by date of a specific set of data that has been joined through multiple tables and then produce all the joined data associated with that first occurrence.

My Current steps:

1. Join 3 tables together based on an specific job id and entity id (each entity has multiple jobs with dates)
2. Create a sub table that pulls out the name of the entity and the first job occurrence.
3. join the two tables created from steps 1 and 2 together to get all the data associated with the first job occurrence. This requires me to recreate the table from step 1 a second time.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Select *
FROM 
     (SELECT FailureTable.*
     FROM 
          (SELECT entity, location, job_end_Date, failure_description
          FROM PF
          JOIN JS ON JS.jobid = PF.jobid
          JOIN WS ON JS.entity_id = WS.entity_id) AS FailureTable
     INNER JOIN
          (SELECT entity, min(job_end_date) AS first_failure_Date
          FROM
               (SELECT entity, location, job_end_Date, failure_description
               FROM PF
               JOIN JS ON JS.jobid = JS.jobid
               JOIN WS ON JS.entity_id = WS.entity_id) AS FailureTable
          GROUP BY entity) AS FirstFailureDate
     ON FailureTable.entity = FirstFailureDate.entity AND FailureTable.job_end_date = FirstFailureDate.first_failure_date) AS FailureTable
```

So this works how I want it to... but it took a bit of manipulation and seems a bit messy and I am having to recreate the table "FailureTable" multiple times to make it work. I don't know how to create the table (by joining multiple tables) so I can reference the same table later in the code for multiple different purposes. Is this possible? Can someone please help with this as I plan to do something similar in other projects.

Thanks!
Kyle

I've tried referring to the original table as "FailureTable" in the second recreation of it, but get errors saying "failuretable not found".